# How to display active directory RTL in Outlook

Tags: c#, encoding, active-directory, outlook, xmldocument

> I'm using System.Xml in order to get data from xml data:
>
> string test = item["name"].InnerXml;
>
> The element name is in the format `xxx ABC ZZZ` where `x` and `z`
>   means Hebrew letters and ABC is English.
>
> The problem is that the result comes as: `test = ZZZ ABC xxx` (Hebrew
>   letters location misplaced)
>
> How can I reverse or align the text to the right in order to get the
>   same text?   If I will assign the variable test to a new one the text
>   will be wrong.

EDIT: im changing the question 
after we figure out that is not a Code thing 
How can i Configure Active Directory to display in Outlook RTL in order to display english and Hebrwe Correctly

Comment: XML now has a RTL property???

Comment: How are you checking the contents of test? It probably has to do with how the debugger displays data and not with the actual data in the string

Comment: @AlexDev in the debugger i can align the text to the right by pressing Ctrl+shift  , if i will assign the variable to a new one the text will be wrong

Comment: The problem is in the **display** - it's very hard to position such mixed contents properly and even the great MS Word never succeeds as far as I can tell.

Comment: @ShadowWizard it a display issue as you mention  lets hope that Microsoft IL Will find a sln for that

Comment: @ShadowWizard in toe worst place ever for any organization
Active Directory and then OUTLOOK... :(

Comment: OMG.. so you will probably need to *manually* switch the positions of Hebrew character sequences - going to be real headache but possible.

Comment: Have you tried my answer below? Inserting the RTL character might do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never tried this but you could try inserting a unicode RTL character "\u200F" at the beginning of the string. See [Right-to-Left Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496819/right-to-left-email).
Otherwise it's probably up to the user to select the display format to RTL.